# Foreach en laravel/blade que itere un array y entregue datos automatizados

Tags: laravel, foreach, blade

Espero esten bien.

Soy nuevo programando y estoy haciendo el tipico blog de laravel, solo que quiero automatizarlo todo, no tener que poner manual cada registro que se que hay en la bdd, sino automatico, con datos sacados de la misma bdd, del backend o de los modelos($fillable o una funcion scope).

Tengo la base de datos, la tabla usuarios, y estoy en el supuesto caso de que no se cuantos registros ni que nombre tiene cada registro, entonces sitúo los argumentos tal que:

```
//backend
// recibo todos los registros de la tabla "usuarios" correspondiente al modelo "User" y los envio a la vista de "users.index" usando with()
$users = User::all();
return view('users.index')->with(compact('users'));
```

hagamos de cuenta que users nos entrega lo siguiente:

```
[
1 : [id: 1, 'nombre ' => 'ernesto', 'edad ' => 30, 'sexo' => 1], 
2 : [id: 2, 'nombre ' => 'luis','edad ' => 20, 'sexo' => 1],
3 : [id: 3, 'nombre ' => 'angela', 'edad ' => 30, 'sexo' => 0],
4 : [id: 4, 'nombre ' => 'katarina', 'edad ' => 20, 'sexo' => 0],
],
```

Como hariamos para imprimir eso en blade sin caer en un "user->name, user->surname, user->etc" con codigo como este:

```
@foreach($users as $user => $key)
         {{user->name}}
```

Cual es el objetivo de esta pregunta? poder reutilizar el codigo en todas las vistas de un sistema.
Se que no resulta seguro mostrar todos los registros de las tablas, pero no es el caso.

Gracias por leer

Comment: No es clara tu pregunta, en resumidas cuentas y sin dar rodeos ¿estas buscando una forma de extraer informacion del arreglo sin usar foreach?

Comment: Buenas! no, disculpa. lo que busco es extraer, con un foreach, el valor de los registros de una tabla y el nombre de los registros.

Por ejemplo si tengo una tabla "users", poder extraerle tanto los campos "name, id, token, etc" como los datos relacionados a esos campos. 

El usuario HeytalePazguato ya me dio una excelente respuesta, pero agradezco tu tiempo. 

Dada su respuesta solo queda procesar los datos con un filtro para que no se envien ni la contraseña ni otros datos sensibles. 
Ademas de usar un str_replace("_", " ", $registry_headers); para emprolijar la info.

Gracias! F N!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer con un segundo `foreach` para recorrer las columnas de los usuarios:

**Nota:** Si la estructura de `$users` es tal como la pusiste en tu pregunta entonces el código que pusiste no recorrería a los usuarios.

Ejemplo para mostrarlo en una tabla:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            @foreach ($user->toArray() as $column => $value)
                <td>{{ $column }}</td>
                <td>{{ $value }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: Mil gracias HeytalePazguato.

 Habia probado muchas cosas, como `get_object_vars($user) as $column => $value` y consulte con cierta IA pero nada, lo que veo es que la sintaxis es distinta: `$user->toArray()`. 
Por lo que veo me falta estudiar mucho mas, pero no encontre el por que de esta sintaxis. 
 Si te sobra tiempo y ganas te pido por favor me lo expliques, seria de mucha ayuda para crecer.
Aun si no fuer el caso muchisimas gracias y felices fiestas!

Comment: @GamalielMatíasCanalesBetes, cuando usas `User::all()` obtienes una colección que tiene la estructura de tu tabla, pero también otros datos, [`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-toarray) convierte la colección en un arreglo de `php`

Comment: Buen día @GamalielMatíasCanalesBetes, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)